# Is the CLR or metro buggy?

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am getting the following error when running my metro app:

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0x6e6b9a68, on thread 0x279c. The error code is 0x80131506.
>   This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

I have a hard time thinking the CLR is buggy.

The app is pure C#, no C++.

I don't use interop.

What should I be looking at?

Comment: keep in mind that metro and .net 4.5 is still in beta, so there very well COULD be bugs in there. also, from what I understand, WinRT is COM

Comment: That's FEEE, the garbage collected heap got corrupted.  Could well be a WinRT projection bug.  Post a repro to connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 1):

If you're building a Metro app, be prepared for this exception to lead to a severe loss of sleep.  In the Microsoft forums, there was a thread a while back where we seemed to isolate the problem to occurring when you are binding with custom value converters.  Really simple converters are fine but interesting ones will yield this exception at seemingly random times.  Good luck.

Comment: Agreed. I spent hours and hours before I realised - the randomness of the exceptions was indeed due to ValueConverters - and I had to change a lot of my app to hack around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Every software has bugs. If this problem is reproducible, you should do this: 1) narrow down the problem to a test-case. This will also ensure that the problem is not on your side, and is really in the runtime. 2) search whether there isn't any already posted bug reports or KB articles 3) submit a bug report to Microsoft.

If the crash is reproducible, I am sure Microsoft will try their best to find and fix the bug.

Comment: The correct venue for reporting possible CLR bugs is [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 is still in beta. I am not sure "buggy" is a fair adjective for software that hasn't been shipped. To your question - they are probably both buggy at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your app is pure c#, any call to WinRT API is an interop between c# and c++.  The interop layer between them is a responsibility of CLR, and that's why the exception said it could be CLR bug.